# difference between "request.user.is_authenticated" and "user.is_authenticated"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication

in django template what is the difference between `request.user.is_authenticated` and `user.is_authenticated`

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

and

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same, it just depends if request.user or just the base request is being sent to the template.

Answer (score 0):

**user.is_authenticated** is True for any User instance, as opposed to AnonymousUser.is_authenticated which is always False.

**request.user.is_authenticated** is populated by the [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) (representing the currently logged-in user), **along with every request**. If the current user has not logged in, this attribute will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser, otherwise it will be an instance of User.

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)